# Magento 2.2 How many websites I can create in community version?

Tags: websites, magento2.2.3

How many websites I can create in community version?

Comment: There is no limit defined I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many additional websites, stores, and store views as you need. You can get more information from below documentation link.

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html